# Modeling recursive fmap (sort of) over a list

Tags: list, function, haskell

I was wondering what the best way is to implement the following problem in a functional programming language (in this example Haskell):

You have a function (or a 'way') that turns 2 inputs, with the type `a` and `b`, in 2 ouputs of the same type (ex: Half adder). Lets call it `f`
in Haskell it would have this sort of type signature
`a -> b -> (a, b)`

And you have a list with elements of type `a`. (or another type of data structure).

Now if supplied with an initial `b` I want the following thing to happen (concept explained with recursive implementation):

Execute `f` with the initial `b` and the first element, modify the `b` and the element with the output of the function and repeat for the next element.

In Haskell:

```
exec _ [] _     = []
exec f (x:xs) b = let (x',b') = f x b in x':(exec f xs b')
```

What would be the best/most efficient way to model this sort of behavior.

Comment: Your function exists in `Data.List` as [`mapAccumL`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:mapAccumL).

Comment: Is that not simply a fold? ``exec values b0 = fst $ foldl (\(out,b) v -> let (o,b') =f v b in (out ++ [o],b') ([],b0) values`` ? The only bad part is that it is not appending on the front here...

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, as you've already implemented the function. Next time you can put the type signature you want into hoogle to find what you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `mapM` for the `State` monad.

OK, expanding a little.

Let's first enter this into ghci and see the type of the `exec` function:

```
Prelude> let {exec _ [] _ = []; exec f (x:xs) b = let (x',b') = f x b in x':(exec f xs b')}
Prelude> :t exec
exec :: (t2 -> t1 -> (t, t1)) -> [t2] -> t1 -> [t]
```

It's almost as you described, except that `t` and `t2` don't have to be of the same type. That's good.

Now, another observation: we actually lose information, when we do what you describe. Specifically, we throw away the last value of `b` (or `t`, as ghci calls it). Let us preserve it for a moment; we can always throw it away later:

```
exec' _ [] b = ([], b)
exec' f (x:xs) b =
  let (x',b') = f x b
      (xs', b'') = exec' f xs b'
  in (x':xs', b'')
```

And ghci says

```
Prelude> :t exec'
exec' :: (t2 -> t1 -> (t, t1)) -> [t2] -> t1 -> ([t], t1)
```

Than we can define

```
exec f xs b = fst $ exec' f xs b
```

But now the type of `exec'` contains a clear pattern. We can make it more explicit:

```
type S b c = b -> (c, b)
exec' :: (a -> S b c) -> [a] -> S b [c]
```

And now it's clear that `S` is almost exactly the `State` monad (well, it's actual definition in a modern setting is a bit more complicated, but not much: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#t:StateT); really, it's just a newtype:

```
newtype State b c = State {runState :: b -> (c, b)}
```

And if we generalize the type of exec' to use an arbitrary monad instead of `State`, we get

```
Monad m => (a -> m c) -> [a] -> m [c]
```

Of course, we can't know for sure that such a thing actually exists, since we only have an implementation for the `State` monad, but... it does. It's called `mapM` (again, it's actual definition in the modern setting is more complicated: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM) — which makes sense, since without a monad it would be just

```
(a -> c) -> [a] -> [c]
```

and that's exactly the type of `map`.

Of course, you can't be sure that `exec'` IS `mapM` without examining the latter's implementation. But in Haskell it just often happens that things that have the same type, if it's reasonably generic, are one and the same.

It also makes sense that `State` monad would be involved somehow — after all, you DO use `b` as a state, changing it as you go through the list.

So, if `exec'` is `mapM`, how do we get back to `exec`? Well, we need to go from the monadic value `State b [c]` to just `[c]`, feeding it some `b`. We can — again — generalize; let's say, we go from `State b d` to `d`, without mentioning the list. And again — there is a function like that, it's called `evalState`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#v:evalState.

So, finally, we are able to produce the final result:

```
eval f xs b = evalState (mapM (\x -> state (\b -> f x b)) xs) b
```

which we can shorten to

```
eval f xs b = evalState (mapM (\x -> state (f x)) xs) b
```

or just

```
eval f xs = evalState (mapM (state . f) xs)
```

or even

```
eval f = evalState . mapM (state . f)
```

We can make it completely point-free, but that would be pointless (and contain too many points):

```
eval = (evalState .) . mapM . (state .)
```

Comment: @Shawn This provides an answer to the question, even if it is a very terse one. @MigMit It would be a good idea to add some further explanation, as the relationship between `State` and the list function in the question likely won't be obvious to the OP, who seems to be a beginner.